# How to score a row based on number of matches in an OR query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-11

I am attempting to score rows based on a set of variable criteria specified with an OR clause and want to return the row that has the high number of direct matches.

This is for postgres <strike>9.1</strike> (edited) *11.1* and my initial attempt (based on a stack overflow article i'm trying to refind) looked roughly like this:

```sql
SELECT                                                                          
  T.id,                                                                         
  (                                                                             
    SELECT                                                                      
    count(*)                                                                    
    FROM (                                                                      
      VALUES                                                                    
        (T.criteria1),                                                               
        (T.criteria2),                                                              
        (T.criteria3),                                                      
        (T.criteria4)                                                              
    ) AS VALS(col)                                                              
    WHERE VALS.col IS NOT NULL                                                  
  ) AS score                                                                    
  FROM my_table AS T                                                     
  WHERE T.other_criteria = 'somevalue'                                                    
    AND (                                                                       
      T.criteria1='foo'                                                              
      OR T.criteria2='bar'                                                          
      OR T.criteria3 = 'baz                                                          
      OR T.criteria4 = 'stackoverflow'                                                        
    )                                                                           
    ORDER BY score DESC                                                         
    LIMIT 1;
```

At first I thought it was working but then I realized that what it was actually doing was simply adding up the number non-null values on the rows that match my OR. Instead of getting the `score` to be a count of non null columns I would like it to be a count of columns that match the where conditions.

For example if I had a row that matched 2 of my OR conditions I'd like it to return a score of 2 and if it matches 3 a score of 3 etc.

I have tried doing things like the following to no avail.

```sql
SELECT 
  T.id
 SUM(                                                                          
    (case when T.criteria1 = 'foo' then 1 else 0 end)  
    ...                              
  ) 
...
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply

```
ORDER BY (T.criteria1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'foo')::integer
       + (T.criteria2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'bar')::integer
       + (T.criteria3 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'baz')::integer
       + (T.criteria4 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'stackoverflow')::integer DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! that was simpler than I thought. I did end up having to use something like `COALESCE((T.criteria1 = 'foo')::integer, 0)` because i was getting null back where the column value was null.

Comment: Also I had the PG version wrong, we are using 11.1 thank god. I edited my original question.